# Can a Blue Prism solution deployed in a machine without an installed Blue Prism?

Tags: blueprism

This is a completely newbie question.

If I have a licensed Blue Prism, I created an autumation using it, can I deploy it to a computer without a Blue Prism software?

Blue Prism is quite expensive and our company cannot afford individual licenses yet.

is there like a compiled exe solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Blue Prism processes cannot be compiled to executable binaries and rely heavily on licensed Blue Prism infrastructure to be executed.

Blue Prism does sometimes offer "development" licenses for non-production use, especially for their clients smaller in size. It may be worth opening a dialog with them to see what terms they might be able to offer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the situation. You usually get Blue Prism developer licenses which a major restriction. Usually when you by the BP license, it is for production usage, meaning when you run your automation via the control room. You should be able to develop and the license would be used to run the automation unsupervised on a runtime machine.

Answer (score 0):

The blue prism license models works based on how many active sessión could be working at the same time. In the image below we could see that this license enable us having 10 robots running different process at the same time, despite of the fact that you could also have this same license install in more runtimes, interactive clients or app servers.

Also you could use this same license for your production environment as well as for your quality environment.

[image: License Description in blue prism studio]

Comment: The question was not about license models.

Comment: But thank you for your input anyway, angelhernandez